# Constructor error: expected ‘{’ at end of input

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

I am having trouble declaring a constructor from in a subclass whose superclass is created from a template.

The example code looks like this:

```
template <class T>
class foo{
    public:
        foo();
};

typedef foo<double> foo_double;

class bar : public foo_double
{
    bar() : foo_double();
};

int main(){
}
```

when I compile, I get an error:

```
In constructor ‘bar::bar()’:
expected ‘{’ at end of input
```

I am at a bit of a loss here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Member initialize list can only be used with the constructor definition. So you need to define it as

```
bar() : foo_double() {}
```

And the base class will be default constructed by default, so you don't need to do it at all. Just

```
bar() {}
```

Comment: It is not a typo if you add a constructor definition in a separate source file.

Comment: @wka Yes it is still a typo.  If you are just declaring the constructor then you would have `bar();`

Answer (score 1):

```
bar() : foo_double();
```

Is not a constructor.

```
bar() : foo_double() { }
```

is.

Comment: Yes.  We should not answer well written questions about commonly encountered errors with no discoverable answers on StackOverflow.  Very foolish of me to not stick my nose up and close vote it.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the curly braces `{ }`

```
bar() : foo_double() { }
              //     ^^^
```